# How does AWS authenticate my signed request

Tags: aws-cli

I am trying to understand how request authentication works on AWS. There is a piece I can't figure out.

There is a lot of documentation about how to sign a request using your secret access key and how to send this signature along with your access key to AWS.
But there is only one sentence on how AWS recalculates this signature in order to authenticate the request. It says that AWS **fetches** the secret key based on the access key and tries to recalculate the signature for comparison.
But what does this **fetch** mean?
Do they store my secret key along with my access key and just look it up?
Or are they able to regenerate my secret key based on the access key?
Can someone shed some light on this, because one thing is clear: AWS needs my secret key to recalculate the signature because I used it to calculate it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - AWS does not disclose how the keys are stored and retrieved.

As you stated, AWS definitely uses your Secret Access Key to recreate the signature.  I can't find any documentation from AWS on how the Secret Access Key is retrieved for this purpose.  The full reference is below, but here is the flow you alluded to:

[image]

AWS considers the AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key to be like a user name and password.

> Like a user name and password, you must use both the access key ID and secret access key together to authenticate your requests.

To your specific questions:

*Do they store my secret key along with my access key and just look it up?*

AWS (to my knowledge) has not published how they store either key but I would assume it's similar to how Unix stores passwords i.e. The user (Access Key ID) is in plain text and the password (Secret Access Key) is either encrypted or hashed. 
 It is secure and cannot be viewed.

*Or are they able to regenerate my secret key based on the access key?*

No, once the Secret Access Key is generated the first time it cannot be generated again.

> You can retrieve the secret access key only when you initially create the key pair. Like a password, you can't retrieve it later. If you lose it, you must create a new key pair.

**References**

[Access Keys and Secret Access Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys)
[To Get Your AWS Access ID and Secret Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html)
[V4 Authenticating Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html)